# Angular - Invalid select type with custom validator

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a select tag in the html like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
          <div>
            <label for="advertisementType">Advertisement Type</label>
            <select formControlName="advertisementType" id="advertisementType" class="form-control advertisementType">
              <option value="-1" selected>Choose one...</option>
              <option *ngFor="let type of advertisementTypesValues" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
            </select>
            <p *ngIf="advertisementType.errors['required']" class="advertisementTypeRequired">You must select one option/p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In the typeScript file the formControl is defined like:

```
   this.advertisementType = new FormControl('', [this.isAdvertisementTypeRequiredValidator]);
```

Where isAdvertisementTypeRequiredValidator method is :

```
  isAdvertisementTypeRequiredValidator(c: AbstractControl) {
    if (!c.parent || !c) {
      return;
    }
    const advertisementType = c.parent.get('advertisementType');
    if (advertisementType.value === '-1' || advertisementType.value === '') {
      return {required: true};
    } else {
      return {required: false};
    }

  }
```

I'm testing this select control, and when I set a value to this, it has the **valid** property with false

```
const advertisementTypeControl = component.adForm.controls['advertisementType'];
advertisementTypeControl.setValue('Service');
fixture.detectChanges();
console.log(advertisementTypeControl.valid);
```

Then the log shows: "false"

Is there something wrong in the method validation? or should I set something else manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its because if control isvalid it should return null as indicator of validity, not `whatever:false`. Antything returned by validator means that validation failed, thus control is invalid.

Unrelated to the issue but to the validator itself: If you put that validator on target control you dont have to get that control again using parent form, as the `AbstractControl c` will be your actual control

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Antoniossss ! I changed the method removing the else body, but when I run the test I have this error: [object ErrorEvent] thrown.